# Clutch pulls in too easy after reassebling the clutch basket, what did I did wrong?

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, kawasaki

I have a 1982 Kawasaki KZ550C LTD. When I got the bike one of the bearings on the starter assembly was worn out and would slip. So I pulled the engine and had to tear it down in order to get to the starter shaft (In this model engine the whole assembly was inside the engine case). Now when I put it back together I noticed that my clutch was way to easy to pull in, before on the bike I would have to pull with at least two fingers to pull the clutch in and now it seems that I can pull the clutch with my pinkie (and it doesn't want to spring back). Everything was put back in the order that was listed in the KZ550 manual. Is there something I missed?

Comment: have you bled the clutch?

Comment: @Mauro - I'm pretty sure this bike has a cable pulled clutch ... http://www.bikez.com/pictures/browse.php?bikeid=19434&pageno=2

Comment: The big question to you is, *does the clutch work*?

Comment: Yes it does. All of the parts are the and was rebuilt by the KZ550 manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clutch actuator that pushes the clutch pushrod for the the throwout bearing and the pressure plate from the left side of the engine to the right side of the engine through the primary shaft has a ball and ramp setup.

By removing the inner actuator for the ball and ramp that has a worm screw actuator you can add a groove by pushing the actuator into the female side of the ball and ramp a groove lower.  This will allow for more leverage in order to actually open the clutch basket up and disengaging the clutch thereby allowing the transmission to spin free of the crank when you pull in the clutch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent!  Glad to hear.  Best of luck to you.